# Auto clicking setTimeout() not working JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to auto click a button after 5 seconds, it does nothing.
*Manually clicking works*

```
<button id="test1" onclick="tFunction()">Button</button>
<script>
  function tFunction(){
    alert("Hello!");
  }
  setTimeout(document.getElementByID('test1').click(),5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout` accepts a *function*. What you're doing is you're immediately calling `.click()`, then passing its return value to `setTimeout`.

Wrap the `.click()` inside a function instead:

```js
function tFunction() {
  console.log("Hello!");
}
setTimeout(() => document.getElementById('test1').click(), 5000);
```

```html
<button id="test1" onclick="tFunction()">Button</button>
```

Also note that `getElementById` is case-sensitive - the last `d` should not be capitalized.

Also, [don't use inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have too many problems and have no place in modern codebases. Use `addEventListener` instead:

```js
const test1 = document.getElementById('test1');
function tFunction() {
  console.log("Hello!");
}
test1.addEventListener('click', tFunction);
setTimeout(() => test1.click(), 5000);
```

```html
<button id="test1">Button</button>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that instant answer, but wrapping .click() does nothing.
I'm just wondering why?

Comment: Works fine here - press "Run code snippet" to see the button being clicked automatically.